# Расчет во втором окне TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

При нажатии на кнопку на главном окне, открывается второе.
Во втором нужно несколько форм для ввода чисел и действия над ними (сложить например).
Не получается задать переменные во втором окне и формулу, при нажатии на кнопку для расчета.
Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# functions:
def glue():
    # messagebox.showinfo("title", "Нажато")
    glue_window = tk.Toplevel()
    glue_window.title('Расчёт клея')
    glue_window.geometry("600x300")
    glue_window.iconbitmap('E:\Projects PyCharm\calculator\ico\calc.ico')

    label = tk.Label(glue_window, text = "Введите значение 1: ")
    label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    label = tk.Label(glue_window, text="Введите значение 2: ")
    label.grid(column=0, row=1)
    label = tk.Label(glue_window, text="Введите значение 3: ")
    label.grid(column=0, row=2)

    def count():
        messagebox.showinfo("title", "Получилось: ", )

    # var's:
    a = DoubleVar()
    b = DoubleVar()
    c = DoubleVar()
    # ============

    one_entry = Entry(glue_window, )
    one_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    two_entry = Entry(glue_window, )
    two_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    two_entry = Entry(glue_window, )
    two_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    count = Button(glue_window, text="Расчитать", command = count)
    count.grid(column=0, row=5)

    label = tk.Label(glue_window, text="кв.м")
    label.grid(column=4, row=0)



# main window settings:
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.geometry("600x100")
root.iconbitmap('E:\Projects PyCharm\calculator\ico\calc.ico')
root.title("Подсчет стройматериалов")

# elements:
glue = Button(root, text="Расчет клея", command = glue)
glue.grid(column=1, row=0)
penoblock = Button(root, text="Расчет пеноблоков", )
penoblock.grid(column=2, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Ошибку выдает, что `messagebox.showinfo("title", "Получилось: ", a.get())` в метод передается 3 параметра вместо 2. У вас только в этом проблема?

Comment: Да и не получается задать формулу, для расчета чисел, введенных в поля

Comment: `Да и не получается задать формулу, для расчета чисел, введенных в поля` - я не понимаю что вы хотите сказать. Распишите по шагам что должно происходить.

Comment: По поводу ошибки - объединяйте строку "получилось" и то что приходит из `a.get()` в одну строку, потом передавайте в `messagebox.showinfo`

Comment: Я исправил код, как вводимые в поля числа сложить? Не совсем понимаю, как работать с переменными

Comment: Пытаюсь так: `messagebox.showinfo("Итог", "Получилось: ", a.get() + b.get() + c.get())`

Answer (score 0):

У вас переменные a, b, c никак не используются. Более того, в данном случае они не нужны, т.к. `Entry` не поддерживает привязку переменных. Нужно брать значение из самих текстовых полей, приводить к `float`, потом уже с этим значением работать.

И еще нужно понимать, что `messagebox.showinfo` не работает как `print`, ему нужно ровно 2 параметра всегда, а `print` может принимать произвольное количество параметров. Поэтому нужно все собирать в одну строку, и выводить вторым параметром.

Пример:

```
one_entry = Entry(glue_window)
one_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

two_entry = Entry(glue_window)
two_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

three_entry = Entry(glue_window)
three_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

def count():
    result = float(one_entry.get()) + float(two_entry.get()) + float(three_entry.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("title", f"Получилось: {result}")
```

Про f-строки вкратце: [Форматирование строк с помощью f-strings](https://pyneng.github.io/pyneng-6/f-strings/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало, то есть, не нужно задавать отдельно переменные и вводимые значение в Entry записывать в них? Можно сразу проводить действия?

Comment: В данном случае да. Можно использовать обычные питоновские переменные, типа `a = float(one_entry.get())`. Но `DoubleVar` на практике вряд ли имеет смысл использовать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, пару дней, как начал изучать)

Comment: @Виталий, если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - поставить галку слева от ответа.